# Post hoc analysis (interaction, multiple comparision, ect.) of regression fitted by```svycoxph```

Tags: r, interaction, survey

Recently I am working with interaction in regression. And I learn a lot from [this](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/seminars/interactions-r/)

The package `emmeans` perform well in various kinds of regression.
However, I found it doesn't work with Complex Survey Design data.
So my question is

1. I would like to conduct multiple comparisons of a multilevel categorical variable in the model fitted by `svycoxph` like this I used to do

```
model<-coxph(Surv(futime,death)~factor(BMI_group),data=data) # BMI_group is a 3 level factor
cat<-emmeans(model,~ factor(BMI_group),type = "response")
contrast(cat,'revpairwise',adjust = 'tukey')
```

2. I would like to calculate the main/simple effect in the model with interaction. Below is the example in `coxph`

```
model<-coxph(Surv(futime,death)~factor(BMI_group)*factor(Sex),data=data) # BMI_group is a 3 level factor, Sex is a binary variable
catcat<-emmeans(model,~ factor(BMI_group)*factor(Sex),type = "response")
contrast(catcat,'revpairwise',adjust = 'tukey')
```

When using the Complex Survey Design data, the codes are as below

```
model<-svycoxph(Surv(futime,Death)~factor(BMI_group),design = Svydata)
```

AND

```
model<-svycoxph(Surv(futime,Death)~factor(BMI_group)*factor(Sex),design = Svydata)
```

Unfortunately package `emmeans` doesn't work

In a word, I would like to know if there is a substitute for `emmeans` to deal with Complex Survey Design data. Or if I can calculate what I want manually?

I hope my expression is clear enough and any insight is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the `qdrg()` function and associated examples. It often works.

Comment: Do the model objects from `svycoxph()` have a variance-covariance matrix for the coefficient estimates? For example, does `vcov(model)` give you a matrix?

Comment: @Russ Lenth
Thank you for your comment. I have tried the `qdrg()` and it works!

Comment: @EdM Yes,```vcov()``` works in the model fitted by ```svycoxph()```. A matrix was shown

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`emmeans()` *almost* works on these models...

Consider one of the examples for `survey::svycoxph`:

```
data(pbc, package="survival")

pbc$randomized<-with(pbc, !is.na(trt) & trt>0)
biasmodel<-glm(randomized~age*edema,data=pbc,family=binomial)
pbc$randprob<-fitted(biasmodel)
if (is.null(pbc$albumin)) pbc$albumin<-pbc$alb ##pre2.9.0

dpbc<-svydesign(id=~1, prob=~randprob, strata=~edema, data=subset(pbc,randomized))
rpbc<-as.svrepdesign(dpbc)

(model<-svycoxph(Surv(time,status>0)~log(bili)+protime+albumin,design=dpbc))
```

If you try

```
emmeans(model, "bili", at = list(bili = 2:4))
```

You get an error message saying it can't reconstruct the data. But that error message also suggests providing the dataset as an additional argument. In this case, be a bit careful because this example actually uses a subset of the original dataset; but it works:

```
> emmeans(model, "bili", at = list(bili = 2:4), 
+         data = subset(pbc, randomized))
 bili  emmean   SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
    2 -0.4309 1.12 Inf     -2.64      1.77
    3 -0.0717 1.12 Inf     -2.27      2.13
    4  0.1832 1.12 Inf     -2.01      2.38

Results are given on the log (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

There is a slight additional complication if you want to get results on the response scale (back-transformed from the log scale). If you ask for `type = "response"` it balks because the model formula has `Surv(time,status>0)` as the response and it tries to undo that transformation too. So use `type = "unlink"` instead, which undoes the log link but doesn't try to undo the repsonse transformation.

```
> emmeans(model, "bili", at = list(bili = 2:4), 
+         data = subset(pbc, randomized), type = "unlink")
 bili response    SE  df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL
    2    0.650 0.731 Inf    0.0717      5.89
    3    0.931 1.044 Inf    0.1033      8.39
    4    1.201 1.346 Inf    0.1336     10.79

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the log scale
```

So in summary, just provide the dataset, and be careful if you want results on the response scale.

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I have provided the dataset as an additional argument in my case, it works and the results are the same as using ```qdrg```, but obviously the former is more concise.

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate what you want manually, although it's safer to take advantage of tools like those provided by the [`emmeans` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=emmeans) to avoid errors.

The coefficient covariance matrix is the key for evaluating hypotheses based on regression coefficients. For this type of model, the coefficient estimates are assumed to have a multivariate normal distribution that includes correlations among the estimates. The standard errors reported in a model `summary()` are the square roots of the diagonal values of that matrix.

You need to use the off-diagonal elements of that matrix for many tests, even though they are typically hidden from the model `summary()`. For example, a test on a linear combination of coefficients (e.g., predictions at particular covariate values) would use the coefficient covariances along with the formula for the [variance of a weighted sum of correlated variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Sum_of_variables). Tests on multiple coefficients at once can use the covariance matrix to perform [Wald tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test#Test(s)_on_multiple_parameters). Apply appropriate corrections for [multiple comparisons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_comparisons_problem).

Happily, if your model returns a coefficient covariance matrix via `vcov()` and a list of coefficient estimates via `coef()`, then the `qdrg()` function in `emmeans` can get those directly from the model, setting up a reference grid that lets other `emmeans` functions do all that work for you. If `vcov()` doesn't return a value but you have another way to get that matrix, you can specify it in the `vcov` argument to `qdrg()`.